# Problems with converting ieeetran to lncs

Tags: lncs

I have to convert my paper from IEEEtran format to lncs and it's my frist experience with this format. For this reason, I downloaded `llncs2e.zip` package and use `llncs` instead of `ieeetran` in the `.tex` file and change the title section.

The first question is the margins when I use this class is different from the margins in the instruction file, I mean large margins. Also, it leaves the first page blank and just put the emails on the top. In addition, there are other problems different from instruction, for example, the captions do not follow the instruction. Shall I correct them manually?

```
\begin{document}

\title{Congestion Control for Vehicular Environments by Adjusting IEEE 802.11 Contention Window Size}

\author{Ali Balador \inst{1}, Carlos T. Calafate \inst{1}, Juan-Carlos Cano \inst{1} \and Pietro Manzoni\inst{1}}
\institute{Universitat Politecnica de Valencia\\Camino de Vera, s/n, 46022 Valencia, Spain}
\email{alba6@upv.es, {calafate, jucano, pmanzoni}@disca.upv.es}
\maketitle
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE of what you have done. The first page blank means that there are some problems with the title section of your paper. If you print on an A4 or lettersize you have "large" but correct margin. For the caption llncs style should produce them with the right formatting (you should not change them manually)

Comment: You are right it should produce them but the captions are not similar to the instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below code and it works.

```
\usepackage{url}
\urldef{\mailsa}\path|alba6@upv.es,{calafate, jucano, pmanzoni}@disca.upv.es|
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\addvspace\baselineskip
\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter  
\title{Congestion Control for Vehicular\\Environments by Adjusting\\IEEE 802.11 Contention Window Size}
\author{Ali Balador%
\and Carlos T. Calafate\and Juan-Carlos Cano\and Pietro Manzoni}
\institute{Universitat Politecnica de Valencia\\Camino de Vera, s/n, 46022 Valencia, Spain\\
\mailsa\\}
```